# Is it possible to combine free space from multiple hard drives under linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, disk-space

Backup and data resilience considerations aside, is it possible under Linux to combine free space from multiple physical hard drives into one bulk drive?

If so, what would be the best approach?

Maybe create multiple VHD, mount those and create a software array out of those?

Comment: Are there any reasons to not combine the _entire_ drives into a single storage array, existing data included? (Otherwise if just the "free" space is taken for the array, there will no be space left for normal data...)

Comment: Looks like what you want is a Distributed Filesystem, which is a form of a cluster filesystem. More information and links to many of them here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system#Distributed_file_systems

Comment: @user1686 the current data is static and free space will not be used otherwise. Beside that, it's more of a "can it be done" question?

Comment: @Silbee not really, but thanks.

Comment: google "btrfs", it might be what you're looking  for... multi-device spanning

Comment: Something worth thinking about is - do you want all this space for "one" large file, or just a large pool of space. Also with linux, you're better off using img files than VHDs...

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I never used the linux lvm, no personal experience involved!

Yes. The easiest approach would be to use the linux lvm (logical volume manager).
If the free space is not used by a partition you could create a partition in the free space and integrate it into your "volume group" which would act as your free space collector.
If the free space is within existing partitions, you would create files in there that use up the free space and you would mount those files as devices.
Afterwards you would include this fresh and new devices into your volume group.

Finally you create a logical volume within your volume group.
You can't directly refer to your collections of drives, partitions and loop devices, you need the indirection of a volume group.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. If free space is not formatted, you could set up a MD RAID0 stripe across those unused partitions. Or use ZFS or BTRFS in a similar way.

If you mean unused space on existing file systems, you could use mergerfs to give you one big logical mount with all of combined free space.